# Query on ContactsContract.data for RAW_CONTACT_ID returns 0 rows

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm trying to get get data from from DATA table for specific RAW_CONTACT_IDs, but all I get are empty query outputs.
The logic seems quite simple but I just can't figure out why this happens. Googled it but couldn't find anything similar.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);    

String where = RawContacts.DELETED + "<> 0 and " + RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "=?";
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                                        new String[] {RawContacts._ID,
                                                      RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                                                      RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                                                      RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
                                                      }, 
                                        where,
                                        new String[] {"Local Phone Account"}, 
                                        null);
int i = 0;
if (c.getCount() > 0) {
    while (c.moveToNext()  && i < 10) {
        i = i + 1;
        // get the id from RawContacts cursor
        String rawID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts._ID));
        tv.append("searching RawID " + rawID + "\n" +
                    "account name: " + c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME))) + "\n" + 
                    "account type: " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE)) + "\n" +
                    "display name: " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY)) + "\n"
                    );

        // create a cursor from Data table for the RawContacts ID    
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                                                new String[] {Data._ID}, 
                                                Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?", 
                                                new String[] {String.valueOf(rawID)}, 
                                                null
                                                );

        tv.append("found " + cur.getCount() + " matches for id " + String.valueOf(rawID) + "\n");
        cur.close();
        }
}
setContentView(tv);
}
```

Comment: `if (c.getCount() > 0)`: this test is not necessary where it is, `c.moveToNext()` returns `true` iff `count > 0`.

Comment: thanks, will remove it. any ideea regarding my question?

Comment: Have you tried narrowing the where clause by removing the `ACCOUNT_TYPE`? Plus if I remember working with accounts in one of the apps and retrieving accounts HTC and some handhelds treat it differently. That `Local Phone Account` may not be reliable.

Comment: It seems that the information is not stored in the way you expect. Follow  @el_bhm suggestion.

Comment: but RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY gives me the names I have for my contacts in the agenda, with the "Local Phone Account" condition. I listed all the account types before and this is the one that stores the info I need.